# Protractor - Can't present and save browser console logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jasmine, protractor

I trying to present on the node cmd and to print out to external log the browser console logs during the automated testing but it doesn't work :/

It doesn't send exception to the Node so I've no idea why it doesn't work.

Please check out the protractor conf file of me and help to figure out what is the reason.

thanks.

**conf file**

```
var log_exceptions = fs.createWriteStream('c:\\automation\\tests\\' + '/exceptions.log', {flags : 'w'});

exports.config = {

   plugins: [{
    path: 'C:\\automation\\tests\\node_modules\\protractor\\plugins\\console\\index.js',
    failOnWarning: true,
    failOnError: true
    }],
},

onPrepare: function() {

// -=-=-=- Console logs handling -=-=-=-
   browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
   // browserLogs is an array of objects with level and message fields
   browserLogs.forEach(function(log){
      if (log.level.value > 900) { // it's an error log
        console.log('Browser console error!');
        console.log(log.message);
        log_exceptions.write(log.message);
        log_stdout.write(log.message);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: What if you print out the `browserLogs` to the console - what do you see? Also, what about that slash before the `exceptions.log`?

Comment: The "slash" isn't the issue here.. it doesn't work with or without it.how can I print the browser logs as you said? just write "console.log(browserLogs); inside some test case? @alecxe

Comment: Yeah, `console.log(browserLogs)` just to see there are logs at this point..

Comment: I've tried to define this function by the code below -     var browserLogs = function( logger, level, msg ){
      browser.sleep(0).then(function(){ logger[level](msg); });
    };
  but it recives "[function]" inside the console and not the errors.